# Twig batch and loop index

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a Twig for loop using the batch filter to wrap every 2 elements in a container div. I want to add a classname to every 3rd and 4th div in this for loop. However it seems you can't use `loop.index` when using the `batch` filter. Is that correct? How do you access the index then when using the batch filter?

What I tried is this:

```
 {% for batch in blog.articles | limit(6) | batch(2) %}
    <div class="blog-art-wrap row-eq-height">
    {% for article in batch %}
      <div class="article {% if loop.index == 3 or loop.index == 4 %}some-class{% endif %}">...... </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

I also tried it with `loop.index3` etc... But it just seems to ignore this. 
Or is this because of the batches are in 2? So there's actually no index 3 and 4?? If so how do you access every 2nd batch then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `parent` [loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) in order to refer to the parent context. As example:

```
 {% for batch in blog.articles | batch(2) %}
    <div class="blog-art-wrap row-eq-height">
    {% for article in batch %}
      <div class="article {% if loop.parent.loop.index == 3 or loop.parent.loop.index == 4 %}some-class{% endif %}">...... </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Try in [this working twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/frme2p).

Hope this help

Comment: Ok never thought of `loop.parent`. I tried your solution and that seems to work....almost :) It appears that also the very last item get that class added. So I have 5 items where 3 and 4 should have that class. However 5 gets that class as well. Any thoughts on that?!

Comment: check the value of the parent loop: it will be incremented by one for every batch

Comment: Yes your right!! I've added parent.loop 3 and 4 but that only need to be 3. It works now.... Thx!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
{% set className = '' %}
{% if loop.index is divisibleby(3) or loop.index is divisibleby(4) %}
    {% set className = 'some-class' %}
{% endif %}

<div class="article {{ className }}">...... </div>
```

Comment: I tried that before but that doesn't work. I think there;s an issue with the batch of two items so index 3 and 4 actually don't exist!